# Liberar memoria de una variable que es puntero (duda de nullptr)

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo un código que realiza lo siguiente:
busca un estudiante por su id, yo tengo un arreglo de estudiantes:

```
vector<Estudiante *> alumnos;
```

y realizo la búsqueda mediante una función que contiene un ciclo, el cual es el siguiente:

```
    for(Estudiante *alumno:this->estudiantes) {
    if((alumno->mostrarId() == id)) return alumno;

    return nullptr
```

ahora esa función retorna a la siguiente variable:

```
Estudiante * incognito = nullptr
```

así lo que hago para saber si existe un estudiante con ese id es comprobar que la variable  no tiene el valor `nullptr`

Ahora mi duda es la siguiente: ¿que hago con la variable `incognito` después de utilizarla, tengo que eliminarla de alguna manera? ¿tengo que dejarla así y la memoria se libera sola? ¿estoy tan confundido que me dedico a barrer en vez de programar?

Intenté con `delete incognito` pero no me compiló.

Comment: No tienes que hacer nada; como `incognito` no fue creado con `new`, no tiene que ser eliminado con `delete`. En el código que pones, el vector `alumnos`contiene una colección de Estudiantes*, mientras que en el bucle for lo que se recorre es otro contenedor `estudiantes`¿Estará bien eso? Pero bueno, supongamos que sí. Después quedaría por ver quién es el responsable de eliminar (`delete`) a esos Estudiantes*, si son o no los mismos punteros de this->estudiantes. Un consejo: aclárate y acomoda la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿que hago con la variable `incognito` después de utilizarla, tengo que eliminarla de alguna manera?

No. La variable `incognito` no se elimina. Esta variable es un **puntero a `Estudiante`** así que lo que harías sería liberar la memoria a la que dicha variable está apuntando.

#### **¿Cuándo debes liberar la memoria a la que apunta un puntero?**.

Cuando dicha memoria haya sido creada con el operador [`new`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

La palabra clave [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) representa un literal de puntero nulo (de la misma manera que el cero (`0`) representa la [identidad aditiva](http://www.mathematicsdictionary.com/spanish/vmd/full/a/additiveidentity.htm) en álgebra). Dado que [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) es un valor literal que específicamente identifica un puntero nulo, no ha sido creado mediante el operador [`new`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) y por tanto no necesita ser eliminado mediante el operador [`delete`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

#### **En realidad, si borras [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr), no pasa nada**.

Según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), aplicar [`delete`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) sobre un puntero nulo no tiene efecto alguno (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.3.5 `delete`
>
> 7. **Si el valor del operando de la *expresión-delete* no es un puntero nulo**, entonces:
>
>    (7.1) — Si el valor alojado por la *expresión-new* para el objeto a ser borrado no fue omitida y su alojamiento no ha sido extendido, la *expresión-delete* debe llamar a la función de des-alojar. El valor devuelto por la petición de alojamiento de la *expresión-new* debe ser pasado como primer argumento de la función de des-alojamiento.
>
>    (7.2) — [...]
>
>    (7.3) — **En caso contrario, la *expresión-delete* no llamará a la *función de des-alojamiento***.

El estándar establece que llamar [`delete`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) sobre un puntero nulo no tiene ningún efecto sobre liberar memoria.

#### **En resumen**.

No debes hacer nada con la variable `incognito` después de usarla, tampoco debes hacer nada con la memoria a la que apunta pues es el puntero nulo (pero si borrases el puntero nulo no pasaría nada), sólo debes preocuparte de liberar memoria cuando ésta ha sido solicitada de manera manual (usando el operador [`new`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)).

Answer (score 2):

> ¿estoy tan confundido que me dedico a barrer en vez de programar?

jeje

Si haces

```
void unafuncion( ) {
  int a = 10;
  ...
}
```

¿ En algún momento *liberarías* `10` ? No, porque es un **literal**. **No** tiene sentido liberarlo, es imposible. Está *embebido* en el código fuente de nuestro programa.

¿ O liberarías `a` ? Pues tampoco, porque es una variable local a la función; ya se libera *solita*.

Pues con `nullptr` es lo mismo. En si mismo es un **literal** ( == 0 ). **No tiene sentido** liberarlo.

Todo esto viene de un tema, los punteros, que es *durillo*, pero, si lo piensas con detenimiento, verás que es mas simple de lo que parece.

```
struct Algo {
  char name[20];
  int temperatura;
};
```

¿ que es `temperatura` ? Desde el punto de vista del compilador, no es mas que una zona de memória, de cierto tamaño, y que admite ciertas operaciones.

Somo nosotros los que añadimos significado *semantico*. Yo **se** que `temperatura` almacena justamente eso, referido a la ciudad cuyo nombre he almacenado en `name`. Y, si quiero que mi programa funcione, he de tener cuidado con lo que almaceno ahí, de forma que sean valores acordes **a lo que yo mismo he decidido hacer con ellos**.

Pues con los punteros pasa lo mismo. Para el compilador, un puntero es un tipo de dato como otro cualquiera; ocupa cierto tamaño, y se le pueden aplicar ciertos operadores. **Una** de esas operaciones es usarlo como *acceso indirecto* a una dirección de memoria, para leerla o escribirla.

El valor *semantico* de un puntero es cosa nuestra. El tomar la decisión de asignarle el valor `0`; o usarlo para almacenar el resultado de una búsqueda; o colocar la dirección de un bloque de memoria devuelto por `new`.

Todas esas cosas son *interpretaciones* que **NOSOTROS** hacemos del **valor** del puntero; el compilador no sabe nada de eso, y se limita a avisarnos si intentamos hacer cosas *curiosas* o *incorrectas*. Para el compilador, el puntero sigue siendo un simple dato, como otro cualquiera.

Con esto quiero decir que si tu haces `int *alto = nullptr;`, el compilador **no** supone ni sabe nada. No asigna memoria; se limita a comprobar que los tipos son compatiles, y *a tirar p'alante*.

Answer (score 2):

Por ponerlo en un contexto entendible por todos, imaginemos el siguiente escenario:

```
class Listado
{
  std::vector<Estudiante*> estudiantes;

  public:
    Estudiante* BuscarEstudiante(int id)
    {
      for(Estudiante *alumno:this->estudiantes)
        if((alumno->mostrarId() == id)) return alumno;

      return nullptr;
    }
};

void funcionCualquiera(Listado& listado)
{
  Estudiante* estudiante = listado.BuscarEstudiante(id);

  // operaciones con la variable estudiante
  // ...


  // ¿Hay que hacer un delete sobre estudiante?
}
```

Referente al comentario de la penúltima línea del ejemplo, ¿quien tiene la responsabilidad de liberar la memoria del elemento? No hay una norma clara a este respecto pero se pueden seguir una serie de pautas para reducir los malentendidos:

- Lo ideal sería que aquel que hace la reserva de memoria sea el encargado de liberarla. Cuando las reservas se hacen en la capa de código X y las liberaciones en la capa Y puede ser complicado seguir la traza de las reservas y es probable que el programa acabe perdiendo memoria. Esta pauta aplicada al ejemplo que he puesto implicaría que sería la clase `Listado` la encargada de liberar la memoria (por ejemplo en el destructor):

  ```
  Listado::~Listado()
  {
    for( auto estudiante : estudiantes )
      delete estudiante;
  }
  ```
- Si el valor retornado por una función no debe ser liberado por quien llama lo recomendable es devolver o una referencia o una copia del objeto (siempre que sea posible). A nadie se le ocurre lanzar un delete sobre una referencia (porque antes tendrías que convertirla a puntero). Aplicar esto a la función 
  `BuscarEstudiante` no es un paso directo, ya que hay que contemplar un modo de actuación para el caso en el que no se encuentren resultados (no puedes devolver una referencia a `nullptr`). Una posibilidad puede ser lanzar una excepción:

  ```
  Estudiante& Listado::BuscarEstudiante(int id)
  {
    for(Estudiante *alumno:this->estudiantes)
      if((alumno->mostrarId() == id)) return alumno;

    throw std::out_of_range("No hay estudiantes con el id indicado");
  }
  ```
- En la medida de lo posible, usar punteros inteligentes. Estos punteros se incorporaron en el estándar C++11. Un puntero inteligente no es más que un envoltorio que se encarga de gestionar el ciclo de vida de un puntero. Hay dos familias a elegir:

  - `unique_ptr`: Este envoltorio está pensado para punteros no compartidos. No se pueden hacer copias y cuando el envoltorio es destruido su puntero muere con el:

    ```
    void func()
    {
      std::unique_ptr<Estudiante> estudiante(new Estudiante);

      // ...
    } // el puntero se destruye en este punto
    ```
  - `shared_ptr`: Envoltorio pensado para punteros compartidos. Permite hacer copias y el puntero no se destruye hasta que no desaparece la última copia:

    ```
    void func()
    {
      std::shared_ptr<Estudiante> estudiante(new Estudiante);

      {
        std::shared_ptr<Estudiante> copia = estudiante; // ok

        // ...

      } // copia se destruye pero estudiante no, el puntero sigue vivo
      // ...
    } // el puntero se destruye en este punto
    ```
- Usar el sentido común: Hay mil situaciones específicas relacionadas con los punteros. Para evitar problemas lo mejor es usar el sentido común y dejar aquellas situaciones dudosas correctamente comentadas para evitar malentendidos. Lo más importante es decidir quien es el propietario del puntero en cada momento para poder adjudicarle la responsabilidad de liberar la memoria cuando proceda. Este punto lo he dejado a propósito para el final porque no habla de cosas concretas sino de conceptos más bien abstractos. En el fondo será la experiencia la que te dicte cómo debes solucionar estos problemas.

Comment: gracias tampoco entendía lo de los punteros inteligentes