# Duda al asignar memoria dinámica a una estructura tipo Matriz en C++

Tags: c++, tipos, estructuras

Sigo haciendo los ejercicios de la universidad y he llegado hasta este:

> Se quiere implementar un tipo matriz. La implementación se quiere que
>   sea en memoria dinámica y en el que cada elemento pueda conectarse con
>   el siguiente en la fila (derecha), el anterior en la fila (izquierda),
>   el siguiente en la columna (abajo) y el anterior en la columna
>   (arriba).
>
> Se pide **implementar un procedimiento crearMatriz10x15** que dada una
>   variable de tipo Matriz cree la memoria dinámica necesaria y
>   establezca los punteros necesarios en memoria para almacenar una
>   matriz de 10 filas y 15 columnas. Todos los nodos deben estar
>   conectados por punteros con sus elementos correspondientes (cuando
>   existan) en la fila de arriba, la fila de abajo, en la columna de la
>   derecha y la columna de la izquierda. Cuando, por ejemplo, un nodo
>   está en la primera fila su puntero arriba será igual a nullptr (dado
>   que no existe fila por encima de él), algo parecido ocurrirá con el
>   puntero abajo en la última fila, el izquierda en la primera columna y
>   el derecha en la última columna.

Tengo este código por el momento:

En la cabecera:

```
#ifndef CABECERA_H
#define CABECERA_H

struct Nodo
{
    float dato;
    Nodo* derecha; Nodo* izquierda;
    Nodo* abajo; Nodo* arriba;
};

struct Matriz
{
    Nodo* primer_elemento;//Puntero a (1,1) de la matriz
};

void crearMatriz10x15(Matriz& m);
//POST: 'm' es una Matriz 10x15 con conexiones de punteros entre filas y columnas
//adyacentes

#endif // CABECERA_H
```

En el main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cabecera.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Matriz matriz10x15;

    return 0;
}

void crearMatriz(Matriz& m)
{
    Matriz* p=new Matriz[10][15];
    p=&m;



    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<15; j++)
            m.dato[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente:
**¿Como hago para asignar la memoria dinámica a la matriz m[10][15], y de que tipo sería el puntero de la asignación?** No llego a entender como comenzar el ejercicio, probé con:

```
Nodo* p= new Nodo[10][15];
//y con:
Matriz* p=new Matriz[10][15];
```

Ambas me dan error.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Se pide implementar un procedimiento crearMatriz10x15 que dada una variable de tipo Matriz cree la memoria dinámica necesaria y establezca los punteros necesarios en memoria para almacenar una matriz de 10 filas y 15 columnas...

una matriz de 10x15 tiene, por definición, 150 elementos... pero en ningún sitio dice que tengas que crear esos 150 elementos de forma individual... simplemente te exigen que hagas uso de memoria dinámica.

Crear la matriz es entonces tan sencillo como hacer una única reserva con espacio para 150 nodos:

```
void crearMatriz(Matriz& m)
{
  const int Filas = 10;
  const int Columnas = 15;

  m.primer_elemento = new Nodo[Filas*Columnas];
```

Para mapear los nodos de la matriz puedes actuar de diversas formas... en este caso como los nodos están contiguos en memoria prefiero optar por aprovechar esa característica junto con un poco de aritmética de punteros:

```
  Nodo* ptr = m.primer_elemento;
  for( int i=0; i< Filas*Columnas; ++i, ++ptr )
  {
    int fila = i / Columnas;
    int columna = i % Columnas;

    ptr->arriba    = ( fila > 0 )? ptr - Columnas : 0;
    ptr->abajo     = ( fila < (Filas-1) )? ptr + Columnas : 0;
    ptr->izquierda = ( columna > 0 )? ptr - 1 : 0;
    ptr->derecha   = ( columna < (Columnas-1) )? ptr + 1 : 0;
    ptr->info = 0;
  }
}
```

Los mapeos de `arriba` y `abajo` son sencillos de explicar: Como todos los nodos estan consecutivos en memoria y cada fila se comopone de 15 columnas... para ir al nodo que se encuentra justo encima basta con retroceder 15 posiciones y lo mismo pero avanzando para encontrar el nodo que se encuentra justo debajo. Dicho de otra forma:

```
m[X+1][Y] = m[X][Y+15]
m[X-1][Y] = m[X][Y-15]
```

Para liberar la memoria, como únicamente se ha hecho una reserva de memoria, basta usar el operador `delete[]`:

```
delete[] m.primer_elemento;
```

Comment: También se adecúa a lo que pedía, como la de @PaperBirdMaster, muchas gracias, miraré las posibles diferencias entre ambos y estudiaré el código. Ando flojo en la asignatura de estructura de datos, me cuesta entender a veces el funcionamiento de la memoria dinámica.

Comment: Una duda, en el bucle for para mapear los nodos, sucedería algo si en vez de `++i` se pusiera `i++`? Tengo entendido que ambos son equivalentes si no los utilizas en una asignación.

Comment: @AguaSal en el caso de un entero no pasa nada... pero en el caso de elementos más complejos (como iteradores) si hay diferencias (`i++` implica un incremento y una copia mientras que `++i` implica unicamente un incremento)

Comment: En este caso entonces se debería utilizar `++i` sí o sí?

Comment: @AguaSal el efecto se nota en términos de rendimiento y no siempre... depende de los requistos de cada algoritmo... en lineas generales para aprender te va a dar igual usar un mecanismo u otro

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo invertido en sacar dudas

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se puede hacer es una lista que contenga listas, para poder simular la matriz hice una ejemplo que te puede servir, espero que sea de ayuda.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
 * Esctructura para los punteros de la matriz
 */
struct Nodo
{
    public: float info;
            Nodo *arriba, *derecha, *abajo, *izquierda;
            Nodo(float);
};

Nodo::Nodo(float valor) {
    info = valor;
    arriba = NULL;
    derecha = NULL;
    abajo = NULL;
    izquierda = NULL;
}

/*
 * En la estructura de la matriz,
 * hay un nodo inicio que es donde se empieza
 * a recorrer la lista de los punteros.
 */
struct Matriz
{
    private: Nodo *inicio;
    public: Matriz(int, int);
            void Ver();
            void Cambiar(int, int, float);
            float Obtener(int, int);
};

// Se rellena la matriz con valores de 0 del tamaño que indique el usuario.
Matriz::Matriz(int filas, int columnas) {
    inicio = new Nodo(0);

    Nodo *tmp = inicio;
    Nodo *antFila = NULL;
    Nodo *antColumna = NULL;
    Nodo *columnaActualCero = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < filas; ++i)
    {
        columnaActualCero = tmp;
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j)
        {
            if (j < (columnas - 1)) tmp->derecha = new Nodo(0);
            tmp->izquierda = antColumna;
            tmp->arriba = antFila;

            if (antFila != NULL) {
                antFila->abajo = tmp;
                antFila = antFila->derecha;
            }

            antColumna = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->derecha;
        }
        antColumna = NULL;
        antFila = columnaActualCero;
        if(i < (filas - 1)) columnaActualCero->abajo = new Nodo(0);
        tmp = columnaActualCero->abajo;
    }
}

void Matriz::Ver() {
    Nodo *tmp = inicio;
    Nodo *ini;

    cout<<endl<<"============="<<endl;
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        ini = tmp;
        do {
            cout<<tmp->info<<" ";
            tmp = tmp->derecha;
        }while(tmp != NULL);
        tmp = ini->abajo;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"============="<<endl;
}

void Matriz::Cambiar(int fila, int columna, float valor) {
    int f = 0, c = 0;
    Nodo *tmp = inicio;

    while (tmp != NULL && f < fila) {
        tmp = tmp->abajo;
        f++;
    }

    while (tmp != NULL && c < columna) {
        tmp = tmp->derecha;
        c++;
    }

    if (tmp != NULL)
        tmp->info = valor;
    else
        cout<<"Los rangos de las filas y columnas superan los limites de la matriz.";
}

float Matriz::Obtener(int fila, int columna) {
    int f = 0, c = 0;
    Nodo *tmp = inicio;

    while (tmp != NULL && f < fila) {
        tmp = tmp->abajo;
        f++;
    }

    while (tmp != NULL && c < columna) {
        tmp = tmp->derecha;
        c++;
    }

    if (tmp != NULL)
        return tmp->info;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main(){
    Matriz m(5, 5);
    m.Ver();

    // Podemos cambiar el valor de una cierta posicion y obtenerlo
    m.Cambiar(2, 2, 5);
    m.Ver();
    cout<<"Valor en (2, 2): "<<m.Obtener(2, 2);
}
```

Comment: Resuelves el enunciado pero no puedo usar TADs en el ejercicio, muchas gracias por el aporte, tu código es bienvenido, lo estudiaré.

Comment: ok, supongo que te da este error: "cannot initialize a variable of type 'Matriz *' with an rvalue of type 'Matriz (*)[15]", no comprendo la logica del código que tu llevas. pero puedes declara la matriz p de este forma `Matriz *p[10][15];` y asi no te va a marcar error en esa linea. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

> **¿Como hago para asignar la memoria dinámica a la matriz m[10][15], y de que tipo sería el puntero de la asignación?**

No lo haces. Estás confundiendo `Matriz` con `Nodo`.

---

Entendiendo que `Nodo *Matriz::primer_elemento` es el elemento de la esquina superior izquierda, si quieres una matriz de 10 × 15 necesitarás solicitar 150 (diez veces quince) nodos:

```
template <std::size_t COLUMNAS, std::size_t FILAS>
void crearMatriz(Matriz& m)
{
    m.primer_elemento = new Nodo[COLUMNAS * FILAS] { };
    // Enlazar punteros...
}
```

No se cómo se supone que debes liberar la memoria de `Nodo *Matriz::primer_elemento`, yo te aconsejaría añadir un destructor a `Matriz`:

```
struct Matriz
{
    Nodo* primer_elemento = nullptr; // Valor por defecto
    ~Matriz() { delete [] primer_elemento; } // Liberar memoria
};
```

Ten en cuenta que si no inicializas elementos de tipo `Matriz` [no pasará nada al aplicar `delete` sobre `nullptr`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55959/liberar-memoria-de-una-variable-que-es-puntero-duda-de-nullptr/55988#55988).

---

Respecto a enlazar los punteros, sabemos que para una matriz de 10 × 15:

- `derecha`: Índice + 1 siempre que el módulo del índice con el ancho no coincida con el ancho.
- `izquierda`: Índice - 1 siempre que el módulo del índice con el ancho no sea 0.
- `abajo`: Índice + ancho siempre que el módulo del índice con el alto no coincida con el alto.
- `arriba`: Índice - ancho siempre que el módulo del índice con el alto no sea 0.

Así pues:

```
template <std::size_t COLUMNAS, std::size_t FILAS>
void crearMatriz(Matriz& m)
{
    constexpr auto elementos = COLUMNAS * FILAS;
    m.primer_elemento = new Nodo[elementos] { };

    for (auto indice = 0; indice < elementos; ++indice)
    {
        const auto x = indice % COLUMNAS;
        const auto y = indice % FILAS;
        auto &nodo = m.primer_elemento[indice];

        nodo =
        {
            .0f,
            x != (COLUMNAS - 1)  ? &m.primer_elemento[indice + 1]        : nullptr,
            x                    ? &m.primer_elemento[indice - 1]        : nullptr,
            y != (FILAS - 1)     ? &m.primer_elemento[indice + COLUMNAS] : nullptr,
            y                    ? &m.primer_elemento[indice - COLUMNAS] : nullptr,
        };
    }
}
```

Por lo tanto, puedes usar la función así:

```
int main()
{
    Matriz m;
    auto crearMatriz10x15 = crearMatriz<10, 15>;

    crearMatriz10x15(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me has robado la respuesta XD

Comment: No te cortes @eferion cuantas más respuestas mejor ¿no? :)

Comment: Se va a parecer bastante a la tuya...

Comment: Todo sea por mantener unas [sanas estadísticas en la etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1998/m%c3%a9tricas-interesantes-para-el-sitio?cb=1#comment6268_2004).

Comment: Bueno, pues ya está publicada... aunque insisto que se parecen jejeje

Comment: Creo que es la respuesta que más se ajusta a lo que buscaba, muchas gracias y ahora me toca estudiarlo y entenderlo.

Comment: Cualquier cosa que no entiendas, no dudes en abrir una nueva pregunta (si tras investigar no te aclaras).