# Métodos para pasar información de una estructura de datos a otra

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos, arraylist

Quiero pasar la información de un "Dynamic Array" a una "Double Linked List", mediante la creación de una función propia de cada clase. Creo que mis algoritmos para hacerlo son correctos, pero tengo problemas con la sintaxis del lenguaje.

He conseguido que una función dentro de la clase de "Double Linked List" devuelva un "Dynamic Array" con la información de la "Double Linked List", pero para ello he de comentar el código del destructor del "Dynamic Array", porque de otra forma me machaca la información antes de que la función devuelva el array, por alguna razón que desconozco.

```
template<class T>
DynArray<T> List<T>::dyn_array_converter() const
{
   DynArray<T> newArray = DynArray<T>();


    for (int i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
    {
        newArray.insert(i, getValue(i));
    }

    newArray.shrinkToFit();
    return newArray;
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el código, el "newArray" se crea correctamente, pero cuando pasa por la línea de código "return", se ejecuta el destructor antes de devolver la variable "newArray", y a continuación me salta una excepción conforme estoy accediendo a memoria vacía. Si comento el código dentro del destructor:

```
template <class T>
DynArray<T>::~DynArray()
{
    /*
    if (arrayElems != NULL)
    {
        delete[] arrayElems;
        arrayElems = NULL;
    }*/
}
```

Entonces funciona, pero dudo que esa sea la manera correcta de solucionarlo. He intentado hacerlo usando punteros en lugar de variables, pero después de todo el verano desconectado no recuerdo muy bien como se usan y debo hacer algo mal, si ese es el problema me forzaré a recordar como funcionaban.

Cuando intento implementar el mismo método para pasar de "DynArray" a "Double Linked List", simplemente no compila y me da problemas con el "template". Adjunto a continuación el código entero del proyecto:

## Array.h

```
#ifndef DYNARRAY_H
#define DYNARRAY_H

#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>


#define min(a, b) (a < b) ? a : b

#define MIN_ARRAY_BLOCK_SIZE 10

template <class T>
class DynArray {
public:
    DynArray();
    DynArray(unsigned int memSize);
    ~DynArray();

    bool empty() const;
    unsigned int size() const;

    bool insert(unsigned int index, const T& elem);
    bool remove(unsigned int index);


    T& operator[] (unsigned int index) const;
    void shrinkToFit();

    void print() const; 
    List<T> list_converter();

private:
    void allocMem(unsigned int memSize);

    T* arrayElems;
    unsigned int memSize;
    unsigned int numElems;
};

template <class T>
DynArray<T>::DynArray() :
    arrayElems(NULL),
    memSize(MIN_ARRAY_BLOCK_SIZE),
    numElems(0)
{
    allocMem(memSize);
}

template <class T>
DynArray<T>::DynArray(unsigned int memorySize) :
    arrayElems(NULL),
    memSize(memorySize),
    numElems(0)
{
    allocMem(memSize);
}

template <class T>
DynArray<T>::~DynArray()
{
    /*
    if (arrayElems != NULL)
    {
        delete[] arrayElems;
        arrayElems = NULL;
    }*/
}

template <class T>
bool DynArray<T>::empty() const
{
    return numElems == 0;
}

template <class T>
unsigned int DynArray<T>::size() const
{
    return numElems;
}

template <class T>
bool DynArray<T>::insert(unsigned int index, const T& elem)
{
    // Return false if the index is out of bounds
    if (index > numElems)
        return false;

    // If the array is full, reserve more memory
    if (numElems >= memSize)
    {
        allocMem(memSize + MIN_ARRAY_BLOCK_SIZE);
    }

    // Shift elements from index one position rightwards
    for (unsigned int i = numElems; i > index; --i)
    {
        arrayElems[i] = arrayElems[i - 1];
    }

    // Insert the element into the empty position
    arrayElems[index] = elem;
    numElems++;
    return true;
}

template <class T>
bool DynArray<T>::remove(unsigned int index)
{
    // Return false if the index is out of bounds
    if (index >= numElems)
        return false;

    // Shift elements at the right of index one position to the left
    // (the element at index gets overwritten/removed)
    for (unsigned int i = index; i < numElems - 1; ++i)
    {
        arrayElems[i] = arrayElems[i + 1];
    }

    numElems--;
    return true;
}

template <class T>
T& DynArray<T>::operator[] (unsigned int index) const
{
    assert(index < numElems && "operator[] out of bounds");
    return arrayElems[index];
}

template <class T>
void DynArray<T>::shrinkToFit()
{
    if (numElems < memSize)
        allocMem(numElems);
}

template <class T>
void DynArray<T>::print() const
{
    if (numElems == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Dynamic array empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numElems; ++i)
            std::cout << arrayElems[i] << " ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DynArray<T>::allocMem(unsigned int newMemSize)
{
    // Allocate memory for the new array
    T *newArrayElems = new T[newMemSize];

    // Calculate the new number of elements
    unsigned int newNumElems = min(numElems, newMemSize);

    // Copy the old array into the new one
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newNumElems; ++i)
        newArrayElems[i] = arrayElems[i];

    // Delete old array
    if (arrayElems != NULL)
        delete[] arrayElems;

    // Assign new values
    arrayElems = newArrayElems;
    memSize = newMemSize;
    numElems = newNumElems;
}


template<class T>
List<T> DynArray<T>::list_converter() 
{
    List<T> newList = List<T>();


    for (int i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
    {
        newList.pushBack(this[i]);
    }

    newList.shrinkToFit();
    return newList;
} 

#endif
```

## List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <iostream> // std::cout and std::endl
#include <cassert> // assert

/**
* Double linked list.
*/
template <class T>
class List
{
public:

    List();
    ~List();

    void pushFront(const T& elem);
    void pushBack(const T& elem);
    void popFront();
    void popBack();
    void insert(unsigned int pos, const T& elem);
    void remove(unsigned int pos);
    DynArray<T> dyn_array_converter() const;

    T front() const;
    T back() const;

    T getValue(unsigned int pos) const;

    bool empty() const;
    unsigned int size() const;
    void clear();

    void print() const;
    void printReverse() const;

private:

    struct node {
        T value;
        node *prev; // pointer to previous node
        node *next; // pointer to next node
    };

    node *first; // pointer to the first node
    node *last; // pointer to the last node
    unsigned int numElems; // number of elements in the list
};

template<class T>
List<T>::List() : first(nullptr), last(nullptr), numElems(0)
{
}

template<class T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    /*
    clear();
    */
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::pushFront(const T& elem)
{
    node *aux = new node;
    aux->value = elem;
    aux->prev = nullptr;
    aux->next = first;
    first = aux;

    if (first->next)
    {
        first->next->prev = first;
    }

    if (numElems == 0) { last = aux; }
    numElems++;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::pushBack(const T& elem)
{
    node *aux = new node;
    aux->value = elem;
    aux->prev = last;
    aux->next = nullptr;
    last = aux;

    if (last->prev)
    {
        last->prev->next = last;
    }

    if (numElems == 0) { first = aux; }
    numElems++;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::popFront()
{
    // Abort if the list is empty
    assert(first != nullptr && "popFront() cannot be called if the list is empty");

    node *aux = first;
    first = first->next;
    if (first != nullptr) { first->prev = nullptr; }
    else { last = nullptr; }
    delete aux;
    numElems--;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::popBack()
{
    // Abort if the list is empty
    assert(last != nullptr && "popBack() cannot be called if the list is empty");

    node *aux = last;
    last = last->prev;
    if (last != nullptr) { last->next = nullptr; }
    else { first = nullptr; }
    delete aux;
    numElems--;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::insert(unsigned int pos, const T& elem)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        pushFront(elem);
    }
    else if (pos == numElems) // position after the last node
    {
        pushBack(elem);
    }
    else
    {
        // Abort if the position is out of the bounds of the list
        assert(pos < numElems && "insert() needs a position within the bounds of the list");

        unsigned int count = 0;
        node *iterator = first;
        while (count < pos)
        {
            iterator = iterator->next;
            count++;
        }

        node *aux = new node;
        aux->value = elem;
        aux->prev = iterator->prev;
        aux->next = iterator;

        aux->prev->next = aux;
        aux->next->prev = aux;

        numElems++;
    }
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::remove(unsigned int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        popFront();
    }
    else if (pos == numElems - 1)
    {
        popBack();
    }
    else
    {
        // Abort if the position is out of the bounds of the list
        assert(pos < numElems && "remove() needs a position within the bounds of the list");

        unsigned int count = 0;
        node *iterator = first;
        while (count < pos)
        {
            iterator = iterator->next;
            count++;
        }

        iterator->prev->next = iterator->next;
        iterator->next->prev = iterator->prev;
        delete iterator;

        numElems--;
    }
}

template<class T>
T List<T>::front() const
{
    // Abort if the list is empty
    assert(first != nullptr && "The list is empty");

    return first->value;
}

template<class T>
T List<T>::back() const
{
    // Abort if the list is empty
    assert(first != nullptr && "The list is empty");

    return last->value;
}

template<class T>
T List<T>::getValue(unsigned int pos) const
{
    // Abort if the list is empty
    assert(pos < numElems && "Position out of bounds");

    unsigned int count = 0;
    node *iterator = first;
    while (count < pos && iterator->next != nullptr)
    {
        iterator = iterator->next;
        count++;
    }

    return iterator->value;
}

template<class T>
bool List<T>::empty() const
{
    return numElems == 0;
}

template<class T>
unsigned int List<T>::size() const
{
    return numElems;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::clear()
{
    node *iterator = first;
    while (iterator != nullptr)
    {
        node *aux = iterator;
        iterator = iterator->next;
        delete aux;
    }
    first = nullptr;
    last = nullptr;
    numElems = 0;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::print() const
{
    node *iterator = first;

    if (iterator == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The list is empty";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << iterator->value;
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    while (iterator != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << " <-> " << iterator->value;
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::printReverse() const
{
    node *iterator = last;

    if (iterator == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The list is empty";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << iterator->value;
        iterator = iterator->prev;
    }

    while (iterator != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << " <-> " << iterator->value;
        iterator = iterator->prev;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
DynArray<T> List<T>::dyn_array_converter() const
{
    DynArray<T> newArray = DynArray<T>();


    for (int i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
    {
        newArray.insert(i, getValue(i));
    }

    newArray.shrinkToFit();
    return newArray;
}

#endif  //LIST_H
```

## Main

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Array.h"
#include "List.h"

    //List into DynArray

    List<int> list;

    list.pushFront(1);
    list.pushFront(2);
    list.pushFront(3);
    list.pushFront(4);
    list.pushFront(5);

    list.print();

    DynArray<int> dynarray = list.dyn_array_converter();

    dynarray.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado a cualquiera que me ayude.

Comment: esto es C# `DynArray<T> newArray = DynArray<T>();`, en C++ no nesesitas especificar el constructor, a menos que sea un puntero, ya que se ejecuta ni bien lo nombras. Entonces seria `DynArray<T> newArray;` y numero dos, ya que estas usando tus propios objetos, olvidate de suponer que los operadores que existen ya estan sobrecargados y funcionan, no lo hacen, tienes que implementarlo todo tu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103015/2742) es correcta pero le falta tener en cuenta unos detalles:

#### (OVR) Optimización del valor de retorno ([RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) en Inglés).

Los compiladores de C++ disponen de un mecanismo de optimización de código que consiste (a grandes rasgos) en construir un objeto que va a ser devuelto por una función fuera de dicha función, ahorrando de esta manera la copia del objeto desde dentro de la función a fuera de la misma. Este mecanismo es automático y sucede fuera del control del programador (y muchas veces sin conocimiento del mismo).

Tu función `dyn_array_converter` crea una instancia de `DynArray` que es perfecta candidata a la optimización del valor de retorno:

```
DynArray List::dyn_array_converter() const
{
    DynArray newArray = DynArray();
    //       ^^^^^^^^ <---- DynArray LOCAL

    for (int i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
    {
        newArray.insert(i, getValue(i));
    }

    newArray.shrinkToFit();
    return newArray;
    //     ^^^^^^^^ <---- Devuelve instancia LOCAL, candidata perfecta a OVR
}
```

Hay varias cosas que pueden evitar que el compilador decida aplicar OVR; un motivo puede ser la complejidad del objeto sobre el que aplicar la optimización, si el compilador no puede deducir que omitir la copia carezca de [efectos secundarios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_secundario_(inform%C3%A1tica)) entonces no la omitirá.

No parece ser tu caso, `DynArray` es una clase sencilla en la que no se aprecian efectos secundarios, por lo que si el compilador no ha aplicado OVR será por la configuración de las optimizaciones del mismo. Intenta aplicar diferentes niveles de optimización y comprueba el comportamiento del programa resultante. Pero...

**No confíes en la OVR para tus algoritmos**.

La OVR es un mecanismo muy bueno para optimizar el código, es muy bueno que exista y no requiere que el programador intervenga para dar lugar a un código optimizado, pero saber que existe no implica que se deba programar confiando en su aplicación.

En tu caso, la ausencia de constructor de copia es un error de diseño, toda clase que maneja un recurso (en tu caso memoria dinámica) debe garantizar que el recurso es correctamente gestionado pero en tu caso no sucede: debes decirle al compilador cómo quieres que se comporte tu clase en caso de copiar el recurso o transferir la propiedad de dicho recurso, si no se lo dices (como es tu caso) el compilador hará el mínimo trabajo posible, y esto en muchos casos será incorrecto.

La propuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103015/2742) sobre un constructor de copia es correcta pero costosa, podrías (adicionalmente) crear un...

#### Constructor de movimiento.

El constructor de movimiento permite transferir la propiedad de un recurso de una instancia de un objeto a otra, en muchos casos esta operación es mucho menos costosa que aplicar una [copia completa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy):

```
//                          vv <---- referencia a valor temporal
DynArray::DynArray(DynArray &&other) :
    arrayElems{other.arrayElems}, // <---- nuestro array es ahora el array del temporal
    memSize   {other.memSize},
    numElems  {other.numElems}
{
    other.arrayElems = nullptr; // <---- el array del temporal ahora es solo nuestro!
}
```

En este constructor de movimiento nos apropiamos (¡le robamos!) el recurso a el `DynArray` recibido el cuál, al finalizar el movimiento no será propietario de ningún recurso. En el destructor no hará nada ya que no tendrá nada que hacer. Por cierto, puedes dejar el destructor así:

```
DynArray::~DynArray()
{
    delete[] arrayElems;
}
```

Ya que [no pasa nada por borrar `nullptr`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55959/liberar-memoria-de-una-variable-que-es-puntero-duda-de-nullptr/55988#55988). El constructor de movimiento será el constructor candidato en tu función `dyn_array_converter`.

Comment: Y si hago ese constructor que propones, ya no tengo que hacer el de copia, o he de hacerlo igualmente? Gracias por el consejo con el destructor :)

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu objeto necesitará gestionar sus recursos en todas las situaciones: creación, copia, movimiento, destrucción, asignación... generalmente si te ves en la necesidad de crear un constructor y destructor es muy probable que tengas que crear el resto de funciones especiales, esto se conoce como "La Regla de los 5". Así que **efectivamente** debes implementar la copia igualmente.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tu haces esto:

```
List<T> newList = List<T>();
```

Estás creando un objeto en la pila. La vida de este objeto está limitada a la propia función. Entonces, cuando pretendes sacar su información de la función:

```
return newList;
```

Lo que sucede es que estás haciendo una copia del objeto... se está llamando al constructor copia. ¿Y qué es lo que hace el constructor copia? Como no lo has implementado el compilador realiza una implementación implícita y esa implementación hace  más o menos esto:

```
List(const List& lista)
  : first(lista.first),
    last(lista.last),
    numElems(lista.numElems)
{ }
```

Es decir, se limita a copiar los punteros de la lista original. El problema es que en este caso, justo después de hacer la copia el programa destruye la copia original y esta copia elimina los nodos a los que hace referencia la copia... no tiene buena pinta.

Quizás la solución más simple sea realizar una implementación propia del constructor copia que sea capaz de duplicar los nodos de la lista. De esta forma cada copia tendrá una lista diferente y la destrucción de una no afectará a la otra:

```
List(const List& lista)
  : first(nullptr),
    last(nullptr),
    numElems(lista.numElems)
{
  if( lista.first )
  {
    first = new node;
    first->value = lista.first->value;
  }

  node* destPtr = first;
  node* origPtr = lista.first->next;
  while( origPtr )
  {
    destPtr->next = new node;
    destPtr->next->value = origPtr->value;
    destPtr->next->prev = destPtr;
    destPtr = destPtr->next;
    origPtr = origPtr->next;
  }
}
```

Por cierto, para facilitar la creación de los nodos, considera implementar el constructor por defecto:

```
struct node {
    T value;
    node *prev; // pointer to previous node
    node *next; // pointer to next node

    node()
      : prev(nullptr),
        next(nullptr)
    { }
};
```

Así no hay que inicializar los punteros del nodo de forma manual cada vez que se crea uno.

Comment: Es decir que tendría que crear un constructor de copia para que el compilador lo usara, pero yo no debería usarlo en ningún sitio, no?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, al final he optado por la solución dada por PaperBirdMaster, ya que parecía más óptima, pero tengo que confesar que entiendo mejor tu método

Comment: @Skyway si su respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución.